# Sectioned UITableView using NSMutableArray of NSDictionaries

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

I have an NSMutableArray of NSDictionaries that looks like this when logged

```
<__NSArrayM 0x165bcfc0>(
{
    SeqN = 122;
    Code = 024;
    Number = 1;
},
{
    SeqN = 132;
    Code = 030;
    Number = 1;
},
{
    SeqN = 124;
    Code = 002;
    Number = 2;
},
{
    SeqN = 114;
    Code = 035;
    Number = 3;
},
{
    SeqN = 144;
    Code = 009;
    Number = 3;
},
{
    SeqN = 444;
    Code = 022;
    Number = 3;
}
)
```

I would like to know the best way to create a UITableView using the Number as sections, so the UITableView would look like this

```
Number 1
SeqN 122, Code 024
SeqN 132, Code 030
Number 2
SeqN 124, Code 002
Number 3
SeqN 114, Code 035
SeqN 144, Code 009
SeqN 444, Code 022
```

I am just lost, I am not sure if I need to spilt the NSMutableArray of NSDictionaries into an Array of Arrays? Or is there an easier solution that can be achieved using something I don't know?

I have managed to create a Unique array of Number that I am using for my sectionCount return. I don't know how to return how many rows per section or split the array so the correct data is being displayed.

### Update

This is how I created an NSDictionary of NSArrays from my NSMutableArray of NSDictionaries

```
 NSMutableDictionary *sortedDictionaryArraysForTableView = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    for (NSDictionary *dict in xmlMArray) {
        NSString *currNumber = [dict objectForKey:@"Number"];
        if(![[sortedDictionaryArraysForTableView allKeys] containsObject:currNumber])
            sortedDictionaryArraysForTableView[currNumber] = [NSMutableArray array];
        [sortedDictionaryArraysForTableView[currNumber] addObject:dict];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your array of dictionaries into a dictionary of arrays of dictionaries where the keys are the `Number`s and the values are an array of all of the dictionaries which contain that `Number`.

The `count` of the dictionaries is now the number of sections. You can use `allKeys` to get all of the numbers (and sort it so you can get the section key and associated array of items).

Answer (score 0):

Reorganize your data so that it looks like:

```
@[
     @{
        @"number":@(1),
        @"items":@[
            @{ @"seqn": @"114", @"code": @"035", @"number:@(1) },
....
     @},
@]
```

basically you want an array of dictionaries, each containing an array of dictionaries (each of which represents your current item)

Comment: Alternatively you can use the @wain's answer, the major difference is that this one results in more complex data, but maintains ordering where a dictionary doesn't.